# Mistake in Bak/Newman -- need help figuring this out

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Bak/Newman and I'm now stuck at the beginning of chapter 5 because I can't figure something out.

> Please could someone help me figuring this out?

The book states the following theorems:

**4.15. Integral Theorem** If $f$ is entire then $f$ is everywhere the derivative of an analytic function. That is, there exists an entire $F$ such that $F'(z) = f(z) $ for all $z$.

The proof is very short and easy and a far as I can tell does not use the fact that $f$ is entire anywhere. I am aware though that any holomorphic function is infinitely differentiable so $f$ would of course have to be entire. What's not clear to me is if it's possible that the proof really doesn't need the fact that $f$ is entire.

Next there is the following theorem:

**4.16. Closed Curve Theorem**  If $f$ is entire and if $C$ is a smooth closed curve,
$$ \int_C f(z) dz = 0$$

Then they define a function $g$ as follows: Let $f$ be entire and define

$$ g(z) = \begin{cases}
{f(z) - f(a) \over z - a} & z \neq a \\
f'(a) & z=a\end{cases}$$

Right after this definition they note that "...$g$ is continuous; however, it is not obvious that $g$ is entire..."

And finally, they state the following:

**5.2 Corollary** Suppose $g$ is as above. Then the Integral Theorem and the Closed Curve Theorem apply to $g$.

**Proof**
We observe that since $g$ is continuous, the proofs of Theorems 4.15 and 4.16 apply, without any modification, to $g$.

However, both theorems assume that the function in the respective theorem is entire!

Is this a mistake in the proof of the corollary and it should say "$g$ is entire"? But if it is then the book omitted the proof that $g$ is entire without even mentioning that they skipped it (despite the remark that it is not obvious).

Comment: We don't have the book or understand the line of deveopment, so how are we even supposed to comment?

Comment: @zhw. I've included all the theorems in the question.

Comment: The question is self contained.

Comment: I think you're right, it should say and prove that $g$ is entire (which it is)

Comment: by the way, theorem 4.16 is definitely false in general for functions that are just continuous instead of holomorphic

Comment: They write "the proofs of … apply … to $g$". Thus look at the proofs of the theorems, not the statements. One can prove both of them using only that the functions is continuous, and holomorphic except possibly at isolated points. If they did that, all is correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, they did that. E.g. the first proof just uses the definition of derivative. What confuses me is: If one can prove a statement about a function $f$ using only that $f$ is continuous wouldn't the statement about $f$ then hold true for continuous $f$: That is, every continuous function on $\mathbb C$ has a holomorphic antiderivative? (I believe this to be false, that's why I'm confused)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki That's exactly why I'm confused: both theorems are only true for entire functions but both proofs only need continuity. So therefore they should be true for continuous functions. But they aren't.

Comment: @student any continuous function on $\mathbb C$ has a continuous antiderivative, but it needs not be holomorphic. maybe what they meant was that the proof of theorem 4.15 also gives the existence of a continuous antiderivarive for $g$, which for some reason is enough for their purpose

Comment: @student They _must_ have used more than just continuity, since the assertion doesn't hold if $f$ isn't holomorphic. Perhaps they used that $\int_{\partial \Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0$ for all triangles $\Delta$?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki What on earth do you mean by "every continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$ has a continuous antiderivative"? That's certainly not true with the standard meaning of *continuous* and *antiderivative*. (Please show me an antiderivative of $\bar z$.)

Comment: @mrf erm... continuous on $\mathbb C$ but real-valued... which I now realize has of course no chance of being relevant in this context

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I think you are right. I just didn't understand that step in the proof (and still don't). Thank you for help!

Comment: @student - I'm coming to this a bit late. But I'm also reading the same textbook right now. I just wanted to say that corollary 5.2 follows from the fact that $g$ is continuous AND $g$ is zero for rectangular curve integrals.